# Reloading routes are returning 404 error in Angular Azure static web app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed an Angular app in azure static web app but I am facing with an error which it is, when I redirect to some routes it is returning me 404 error, but if I am in web app and I go from one route to another then it is working.
I tried to change the baseRef in index.html but no success
Local it is everything working as expected

I have used `ng build --prod` to deploy the app.

I used Linux as server in Azure Web Static which the deploy process is in `yml` file.

I have seen the documentation of the Microsoft but didn't understand to much.

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v0.0.1-preview
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_RED_BAY_017ABB010 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/" # App source code path
          api_location: "api" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "dist" # Built app content directory - optional
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v0.0.1-preview
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_RED_BAY_017ABB010 }}
          action: "close"
```

And this is the the `angular.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "smart-career-ng": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "lodash",
              "jwt-decode"
           ],
            "aot": true,
            "outputPath": "dist/smart-career-ng",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "./node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.min.css",
              "./node_modules/quill-emoji/dist/quill-emoji.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              "node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "smart-career-ng:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "smart-career-ng:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "smart-career-ng:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",

            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "smart-career-ng-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "smart-career-ng:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "smart-career-ng:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "smart-career-ng",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

I have created a `web.config` but I don't know to much about it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/src/index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And this is the `index.html` in the `dist` folder

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SmartCareer</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <style type="text/css">@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc-.woff) format('woff');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxM.woff) format('woff');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc-.woff) format('woff');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7GxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxKKTU1Kg.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v27/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}</style>
  <style type="text/css">@font-face{font-family:'Material Icons';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v84/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNa.woff) format('woff');}.material-icons{font-family:'Material Icons';font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-size:24px;line-height:1;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;display:inline-block;white-space:nowrap;word-wrap:normal;direction:ltr;font-feature-settings:'liga';}@font-face{font-family:'Material Icons';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v84/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2) format('woff2');}.material-icons{font-family:'Material Icons';font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-size:24px;line-height:1;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;display:inline-block;white-space:nowrap;word-wrap:normal;direction:ltr;-webkit-font-feature-settings:'liga';-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;}</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.985f0618be000afa89be.css"></head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.359d5ee4682f20e936e9.js" defer=""></script><script src="polyfills-es5.67365ac3ab216b9b9f44.js" nomodule="" defer=""></script><script src="polyfills.dbb6b06725eba392f879.js" defer=""></script><script src="scripts.6cace4b00cf6f5a20a53.js" defer=""></script><script src="main.772684a77b001b3848c3.js" defer=""></script></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 41):

For **Single page app which uses client-side routing**.

Navigating to "products"
https://beatiful-snow-XXXXXXX.azurestaticapps.net/products
then reloading the page will result in the web server trying to look for products.html which does not exist, that's why you got 404 error.

To resolve this, you need to add fallback routes in **staticwebapp.config.json** file:

```
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html",
    "exclude": ["/images/*.{png,jpg,gif}", "/css/*"]
  }
}
```

To know more:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#fallback-routes

Comment: This should be marked the correct answer. This is the correct implementation --use `navigationFallback` instead of `routes`. This also works on the cloud emulator, sweet. Awesome work, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the filename. Just checked the docs and didn't see that little detail.

Comment: This worked for me. Some of the urls on my angular app wasn't working. I had to add a ```staticwebapp.config.json``` inside the assets folder and then update ```config_file_location: src/assets``` in the yml inside workflows directory inside .github folder

Answer (score 5):

For all people that will see question, here is the answer.

You need to create under assets a file which is called `routes.json` and there you parse this code.

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/*",
      "serve": "/index.html",
      "statusCode": 200
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you build the project and deploy to the Azure Static Web App

Comment: now the replacement of routes.json, is staticwebapp.config.json https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#example-configuration-file

Answer (score 0):

As the base base URL of your app is direct you have to place "/" instead of /src/index.html in the rewrite tag. Please try the below code in your web config file.
For reference follow the link: http://sundeepkamath.in/posts/hosting-angular-application-in-iis-server/

```html
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        <!--<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />-->
        </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I dont have a IIS Server, das wird alles in Azure Deployed as Azure Static Web.

Comment: But the web config syntax and all are similar to IIS I presume. Sorry if that is wrong I thought you would give it a try. Thank You

Comment: I was able to fix it.

Comment: Ohh great how did you do that ?

Comment: Come on, don't be a DenverCoder9 @TheCoderGuy